# Форма слова "красивый"

Tags: лингвистика

Какое из перечисленных слов не является формой слова "красивый"? 
А) Красивее
Б) Самый красивый
В) Красавчик
Г) Наикрасивейший
Д) Красивым

Answer (score 1):

Варианты А,Б,Г - формы степеней сравнения прилагательного *красивый*, вариант В - однокоренное слово. Вариант Д - падежная форма названного прилагательного. Таким образом, действительно, только слово *красавчик* лишнее.

Answer (score 1):

Ни одно, кроме Д.
А) Красивее - не форма слова, а другое слово, сравнительная степень.
Б-Г) Наикрасивейший - превосходная стпень, это не форма исходного красивый. Тем более - "самый красивый". Это вообще не одно слово.

Хотя оговорюсь, возможно в школе по-другому учат. Это тема, думаю, класса третьего, вряд ли там даёт хотя бы отдалённое представление о словоформе (по Фортунатову и другим).

Comment: Сравнительная и превосходная степень - это ФОРМА прилагательного.

Comment: Это по какому учебнику?

От из Вики, например:
**Фо́рма сло́ва — морфологическая разновидность слова, несущая комплекс тех или иных значений присущих данной части речи грамматических категорий[1]; совокупность морфологических и фонологических характеристик слова (формальных показателей, в том числе нулевых[1]), указывающих на его грамматическое значение[2] — принадлежность к определённым грамматическим категориям.**

Другими словами, форма слова - набор словоизменяющих признаков.
Образование степеней сравнения - словообразование.

Comment: Ну если очередное светило не написало очередной учебник. Тут я действительно - пас.

Comment: Суффиксы степеней сравнения относятся к формообразовательным, а не к словообразовательным. Следовательно, степени сравнения прилагательных - формы слова, а не новые слова. (см. Большой лингвистический словарь В.Д. Стариченка. Ростов-на-Дону, 2008. С.631. Статья "Суффикс").

Comment: Присоединяюсь к olsa. Я не буду лезть в споры, но, как практик, отмечу, что на ЕГЭ степени сравнения прилагательных и наречий рассматриваются как формы слова, а их суффиксы как формообразовательные.

Comment: >>>Суффиксы степеней сравнения относятся к формообразовательным, а не к словообразовательным. 
Не совсем понятно, на тавтологию смахивает. Не буду сейчас заострять, ибо посмотрел у Литневской, там действительно противопоставлены формообразующие суффиксы и словообразующие (что спорно) и суффиксы степеней сравнения отнесены к последним. Не знаю, только ли для школьных нужд или сейчас наука такая.  

Вопрос пока в другом. "Наши"-то слова в вопросе образованы не только суффиксами, там еще и префикс вылез в одном случае, а в другом - так вообще целое слово. С ними-то как, тоже "формообразующие"?

Answer (score 0):

Существительное красавчик.

Comment: спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

форма слова - это то же самое слово с другим окончанием или суффиксом. Красавчик - однокоренное слово, оно лишнее.

Comment: Это откуда тиакая формулировка про окончания и суффиксы?

Answer (score 0):

Степени сравнения  прилагательных - формы слова. По всем школьным учебникам. И не только.Заглянем в словарь. На букву К  найдем красивый, красавец, красивость. И никаких слов красивее и красивейший - нет.
Но в связи с этим другой вопрос:  степени сравнения - это формы слова, наречия, образованные от качественных прилагательных тоже имеют степени сравнения, следовательно, наречия имеют формы слова. Почему наречия - неизменяемая часть речи? Потому что не склоняется и не спрягается?

Comment: Бедный Фортунатов. 
А как там "во всех школьных" ввождится понятие формы слова? Что оно вообще такое? И чем тогда "Красачик" не угодил? По той же схеме сработано - заменой суффикса.    

Словарь - не аргумент. Там можно и совершенный вид найти при несовершенном. Тоже - форма слова?

Comment: Про наречия вообще ничего не понял. Они неизменяемы по грамматике русского языка. Задавать вопрос "Почему?" в подобных случая не приходится. Иначе придется отвечать на все вопросы типа "Почему подлежащее всегда стоит в именительном падеже? Почему у глагола два числа и три лица?"

Comment: Кстати, а в какой словарь вы смотрите? В орфоэпическом Аванесова, например, всё есть. И "красивее" и "красивейший".
И у Лопатина - есть. И у Зарвы - тоже. Это из тех, что под рукой и/или в сети есть в прямой доступности.

Comment: Формы одного и того же слова не отличаются лексическим значением, отличаются только грамматическим. Изменяя существительные по падежам и числам, например, получаем формы существительного. Суффикс (словообразовательный) меняет лексическое значение. 
В школьной грамматике -традиционная точка зрения на степени сравнения. В "Грамматике - 80" степени сравнения считаются разными словами. Поэтому однозначного ответа на данный вопрос нет. В школе следует ответить на данный ответ "красавчик", а в вузах, наверное, рассматриваются разные точки зрения.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что формой слова "красивый" не является слово "красавчик", оно имеет другое лексическое значение. Остальные слова являются формами данного слова. Красивее - сравнительная степень прилагательного , обозначающая, что признак присутствует в большей степени; самый красивый и наикрасивейший - превосходная степень  прилагательного соответственно в составной(из 2 слов) и простой (из 1 слова) форме, обозначающие, что признак присутствует в наивысшей степени.
Красивым - это форма творительного падежа, мужского рода,единственного числа.

Описание

кратко опишите изменения (исправление ошибок в орфографии, форматировании)
 Сохранить изменения отмена
Руководство По Редактированию

► исправить грамматические или орфографические ошибки

► уточните смысл, не изменяя его

► исправьте незначительные ошибки

► добавить связанные ресурсы или ссылки

► всегда проявляйте уважение к автору

Основы Форматирования

► ставьте перевод строки между абзацами